# Why the button inside table in modal not working?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Why is the button inside the table row not working?

I am only expecting it to print a message in the console by calling a function in the `modal-basic.ts` file.

**modal-basic.html:**

```html
<td><button (click)="test()">Test</button></td>
```

**modal-basic.ts:**

```js
test() {
  console.log("Test...");
}
```

You can find a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the following StackBlitz: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpp4uh**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users For further information, please see how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , and take the tour of the site (https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I don't have more time to spend looking at it but I did notice that changing it from a button to anything else makes the function executable. e.g. change your `<td><button (click)="test()">Test...` to `<td><p (click)="test()">Test...`. When you do this and click on the `<p>` tag the first time it will not execute, but the second time you click on the `<p>` tag it will execute. Extremely strange. Good luck.

Comment: The reason why the button doesn’t work is because the method is inaccessible from the `ng-template` that the modal template is in.

Comment: I don't think being in the `ng-template` is the issue here. You can place the `<button (click)="test()">Test</button>` just outside the `<tr>` tag and it will then work (still being inside the modal). this is definitely not the intended behaviour

Comment: @Edric at first i thought that too, i was thinking that the context is different. However as @Andrew Hill wrote it starts to work when you change `button` to `p`. Adding `trackBy: trackByFn` to `*ngFor` where `trackByFn = (index, item) => index` also fixes the `click` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some changes.

removed this code in ts.

```
 get countries(): Country[] {
    return COUNTRIES
      .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
      .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
  }
```

declare

```
countries = [];
```

add in ngOnit or constructor()

```
{this.countries = COUNTRIES;}
```

In html

```
 *ngFor="let country of countries | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize"

<ngb-pagination
  [(page)]="page"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [collectionSize]="countries.length"></ngb-pagination>
```

here is the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dxiv4

Comment: If this is your question, post above. Here, your are answering the question.